# hook_form_search_block_form_alter is not working with bootstrap theme?

Tags: theming, 8, hooks

I am facing an issue where [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.2.x) code is working in bartik theme while same is not working in [Bootstrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap). Any idea what could be the reason or am I missing something? Very Thanks.

***In THEMENAME.theme of bootstrap theme***

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Bootstrap sub-theme.
 *
 * Place your custom PHP code in this file.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute;


function subtheme_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Sentence for placeholder!!!.');  
}
```

***OtherWay,***

```
function subtheme_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'search_block_form'){
      $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Sentence for placeholder!!!.');
    }
}
```

***In bartik.theme***

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Functions to support theming in the Bartik theme.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute;

function bartik_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Sentence for placeholder!!!.');  
}
```

Comment: You have two placeholders for the theme name. Are they the same THEMENAME == subtheme?

Comment: @4k4 Hi, yes it is my actual sub theme name.

Comment: I would try a less specific THEMENAME_form_alter() and debug the form_id's that are coming in.

Comment: @4k4  I will try that way and will let you know.

Comment: @4k4 I have tried that way also, but no luck, updated the question with the code which I have used. Any suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a bootstrap plugin:

**themes/THEMENAME/src/Plugin/Form/SearchBlockForm.php**

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\THEMENAME\Plugin\Form\SearchBlockForm.
 */

namespace Drupal\THEMENAME\Plugin\Form;

use Drupal\bootstrap\Annotation\BootstrapForm;
use Drupal\bootstrap\Utility\Element;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 *
 * @ingroup plugins_form
 *
 * @BootstrapForm("search_block_form")
 */
class SearchBlockForm extends \Drupal\bootstrap\Plugin\Form\SearchBlockForm {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alterForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id = NULL) {
    // Call the parent method from the base theme, if applicable (which it is
    // in this case because Bootstrap actually implements this alter).
    parent::alterForm($form, $form_state, $form_id);

    $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Sentence for placeholder!!!.')
  }
}
```

Reference:

http://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs%21plugins%21Form.md/group/plugins_form/8